# Covering number of the range of a function

Tags: reference-request, mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, covering, sphere-packing

I have come across the need to know a bound on a certain curious quantity: the covering number of the range of a continuous function $f: D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$, where $D \subseteq \mathbb{R}^m$. i.e., I need an upper bound on the minimum number of $\epsilon$-radius (open) norm balls needed to cover the set $R=\{f(x) | x \in D\}$. We may assume that $R$ is compact and if necessary also assume that $D$ is compact. I am completely knew to this kind of mathematics. I would like to thus know:

- What is known about this number?
- One, albeit weak, bound is simply the covering number of the ball in which $R$ lies. What is the best known result here?
- What body of literature has results like these?

**Edit:** In case there is no general answer, I thought I will narrow down the question. I am actually interested in a rather specific case. My $f$ is the (unique) solution of an ODE. Thus, $D=[0,\infty)$ and $f$ is in $C^1$.

Comment: What do you know about $f$?

Comment: I have added a few edits and more details about $f$. Thanks!